# Manipulating radius of multiple circles simultaneously

Tags: graphics, manipulate

I have a random data set,

```
points = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}]
```

and from that set I'd like to plot vertices, and circles with a variable radius which I can manipulate.

How can I introduce a variable radius parameter into the following code so that I may manipulate the radius in the graphics?

```
Graphics[{
  GraphicsComplex[
   points,
   {
    Line[{}],
    Red,
    PointSize[.02],
    Point[points]
    }
   ], GraphicsComplex[
   points,
   Circle /@ points
   ]}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[0];

points = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}];

Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   Circle[#, r] & /@ points,
   Red, PointSize[.02], Point[points]},
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}],
 {{r, .2, "radius"}, 0.03, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]